# Iron Router doesn't update

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm trying to update to the version 0.6.2, but when I insert mrt update iron-router in the command line I receive this alert:

Problem installing iron-router
  ✘ [0.6.1] conflicts with [0.6.2]
Can't resolve dependencies! Use --force if you don't mind mrt taking a wild guess and running your app anyway.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a fresh installation:

```
meteor remove iron-router
rm -rf packages/iron-router
mrt update
meteor add iron-router
```

Also make sure you're using the latest version of meteorite

```
sudo -H npm install meteorite
```

Comment: I've done that, but I'm still receiving the same error: Problem installing iron-router
  ✘ [0.6.1] conflicts with [0.6.2]
Can't resolve dependencies! Use --force if you don't mind mrt taking a wild guess and running your app anyway. And when I try to start the app it says that While building package `iron-router-progress`:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'

Comment: Your `smart.json` file might be incorrect, could you try removing the iron-router lines from there (and `smart.lock`) and running `mrt add iron-router`?

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't work and now I don't even have the version 0.6.1 installed

Comment: Could you give a bit more details on your setup? what is in your `smart.json` and what version of meteorite are you using

Comment: In my smart.json I have this {
  "packages": {
    "spin": {},
    "momentjs": {},
    "iron-router-progress": {},
    "zurb-foundation": {},
    "accounts-entry": {}
  }
}
and the meteorite is meteorite@0.7.1

Comment: I think the problem is related with the accounts-entry

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one of the other smart packages you are using explicitly depends on a different version of Iron Router. Based on the `smart.json` packages that you posted, `accounts-entry` depends on 0.6.1 and I'm guessing you are manually depending on iron router 0.6.2 in your main app.

The best course of action is to probably change the version in `accounts-entry` (it will probably not break anything, as 0.6.1 to 0.6.2 was just bug fixes) and possibly submit a pull request for that as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that

Answer (score 1):

Had a Similar problem.
Go to you app directory, open meteor, then open packages and you will see

```
iron-router
```

inside the file listed as a meteor package.

Then go to the terminal and

```
cd yourApp
meteor add iron:router
```

for me that added the 1x version and solved many of my errors.

Hope it works!